# Decimals in the user interface Dapps

Tags: ethereum

When sending transactions on an ERC20 token, with the decimal variable set to 18, you must multiply values by 10^18. I don't want to make the users of the dapp multiply their values by that amount. It would be very user unfriendly. How do you resolve this problem? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Your code can multiply for them. Simply take the input value and multiply by 10^18.

```
<input type="text" name="to" value="0x123">
<input type="number" name="amount" value="5">
```

```
const inputMock = {
    to: '0x123',
    value: 5
};

const myContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abiJson, contractAddress);
const txData = myContract.methods.transfer(
    inputMock.to,
    web3.utils.toWei(inputMock.value) // multiplies by 10^18 and returns the number as a string
);
```

Docs: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/web3-utils.html#towei

Comment: Thank you for the response! This helped me resolve the problem.